# How to pass data from one state to another as params or using Angular Service.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following success function :

```
if(data.status=="success")  {               
  var sessionid = data.member.member_id;
  var dd = data.member;
  $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {userid: sessionid});
}
```

data.member contains JSON data I dont want only data.member.member_id; but I want all objects present in data.member that data has to be sent to dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault.

The two states are:

```
.state('dashboardsnewsucc', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboardsnewsucc/:userid",
            templateUrl: "views/common/content-empty.html",
        })

        .state('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {
            url: "/dashboardefault",
            templateUrl: "views/userdashboard.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Hive Dashboard',specialClass: 'loginscreen-gray-bg' },           
        })
```

In front end am fetching data.member.member_id as `{{$state.params.userid}}.`

Comment: try to send data as JSON string JSON.stringify(data.member) and at the point of capturing do a JSON.parse($state.params.userid)

Comment: Am new to angular JS can you describe with syntax if you dont mind.

Comment: $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {userid: JSON.stringify(sessionid)});

Comment: Thats working but in URL am getting many values is there an option to send like an POST type...

Comment: I have a lot of data in data.member thats why..

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
$stateProvider
.state('dashboardsnewsucc', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboardsnewsucc',
    controller:  'dashboardsnewsuccCtrl'
})
.state('view', {
    templateUrl: 'dashboardsnewsucc',
    params:      {'param': null, 'paramOther': null}, // Set By Default Values
    controller:  'dashboardsnewsuccCtrl'
})
```

send params:

```
$state.go('view', { 'param': 123, 'paramOther': 'This is a test' })
```

then access in your controller:

```
app.controller('dashboardsnewsuccCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
 var index = $stateParams.param;
 var anotherKey = $stateParams.paramOther;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For doing what you are trying to achieve you can simply pass the whole object instead of passing only one object property. For example here you are first retrieving the `member_id` and then you are passing only that value to the next state.

But instead of doing that you can write it like this:

```
if(data.status=="success")  {               
    var sessionid = data.member.member_id;
    var dd = data.member;
    $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', 
        {
            member: dd
        }
    );
}
```

This will pass the whole member object to the next state and you can access the whole member object in your next state like:
`$state.params.member`
which will give you the complete member object with all the properties in it as it was returned in the previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as string

```
if(data.status=="success")  {               
  var sessionDetails = JSON.stringify(data.member);
  var dd = data.member;
  $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {userid: sessionDetails});
}
```

while in the controller of `dashboardsnewsucc`

```
var sessionDetails = JSON.parse($state.params.userid)
```

Although I feel like your relevant details makes more sense to store in cookies.

Comment: Since data.member contains credentials I cannot pass as parameter... Any other options..

Comment: I already commented in my answer that looking into your que it make more sense to store in cookies but `password` ? that should never be handled in UI instead use token if you want to store session details

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your data first.

```
if(data.status=="success")  {               
  var sessionid = data.member.member_id;
  var dd = data.member;
  $state.go('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {userid: JSON.stringify(sessionid)});
}
```

And inside controller , where yoy fetching the data,You need to again Parse the JSON

```
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
 var userid = JSON.parse($stateParams.userid)

})
```

If You dont want to show data in URL:

```
state('dashboardsnewsucc', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/dashboardsnewsucc",
         params: {
             userid:null
          }
            templateUrl: "views/common/content-empty.html",
        })

        .state('dashboardsnewsucc.dashboardefault', {
            url: "/dashboardefault",
            templateUrl: "views/userdashboard.html",
            data: { pageTitle: 'Hive Dashboard',specialClass: 'loginscreen-gray-bg' },           
        })
```

Comment: Am using Angular framework.. I have controller function like this.
function MainCtrl($http,$state) {
How to do in this way..

Comment: Just  MainCtrl($http,$state,$stateParams).

Comment: How to get data from there. I used like this. {{$state.params.userid}}..

Comment: @PrashanthHarish  what you get when $state.params.userid?

Comment: I have a problem. Since this is login application If I go back then every data is erased..

Comment: Just pass it as you passesd userid. Just stringify JSON before you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Routes**:

```
.state('some-state', {
        url: 'someUrl',
        parent: 'home',
        params: {
          myObj: null
        }});
```

Let's say you want to receive an object to state **S2** from **S1**, So, on **S1**:

```
var params = {
          myObj: "HELLO FROM THE OTHER SIDE"
        };
        $state.go("confirmation-auth-email", params);
```

On **S2** you receive like this:

```
function someControllerFunction($scope,$state) {console.log(JSON.parse($state.params));}
```